# How to remove bottom border from menu

Tags: semantic-ui

I know that `borderless` class removes the border between menu items, but I am interested in removing the bottom border on the whole menu.

I tried adding `border-bottom: 0px none;` in css to an id attached to the "ui menu" div but it has no effect.

Why doesn't this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include `!important` in that CSS rule. Also, add `box-shadow: none`.

```css
.ui.menu {
  border-bottom: 0 none !important;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.3.3/dist/semantic.min.css">
<div id="menu" class="ui three item menu">
  <a class="item active">Editorials</a>
  <a class="item">Reviews</a>
  <a class="item">Upcoming Events</a>
</div>
```